# Avoid elem.onclick override action in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, overriding

I have a question about a `onclick`'s JavaScript behavior. I have two JavaScript classes that initialize a `onclick` function in a element, but when I apply the `onclick` initializers on the same html element only works the last `onclick` function, I don't understand this behavior. I test to get the same situation in a simple example and the results are the same. Here's my example code with this strange behavior:

```
window.onload = function ()
    {
        var testElem = document.querySelector('#test_element');

        test_element.onclick = function ()
        {
            alert('one');
        }

        test_element.onclick = function ()
        {
            alert('two');
        }
    }
```

And here is my HTML

```
<div id="test_element">click here to test_element</div>
```

When I click on the trigger I need to throw the two alerts "one" and "two" but it seems like the second overrides the first. Please, somebody can help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), which can handle multiple handlers for the same event:

```
test_element.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('one');
}, false);

test_element.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('two');
}, false);
```

The `onclick` property (aka inline) only supports a single handler.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `addEventListener(eventName, handler)`, which is the correct way to add handlers in JS.

It will let you add as many handlers as you want.